# Как реализовать такие части блоков (timeline)

Tags: css3, timeline

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как реализовать обтекание логотипа белым фоном, и чтобы логотип был в контейнере?

И как реализовать (timeline) пунктов преимущества как добавить линию между пунктами?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Timeline

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: #FDB700;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.timeline {
  counter-reset: timelineItem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 15px;
  position: relative;
}

.timeline:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 15px;
  width: calc(100% - 30px);
  height: 2px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .35);
}

.timeline>li {
  list-style: none;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #FFD251;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.timeline>li:before {
  counter-increment: timelineItem;
  content: counter(timelineItem, decimal-leading-zero) " ";
}
```

```html
<ol class="timeline">
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ol>
```

Menu

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    background: #FDB700;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
li{
    list-style: none;
}

nav{    
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.nav-menu{
    padding: 1em;
    display: flex;    
}
.nav-menu > li{
    padding: 5px;
}

.nav-logo{
    padding: 1em;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background: #fff;
    position: relative;    
}
.nav-logo:after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute; bottom: 0; right: -45px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 0 100% 100% 0;
}
.nav-logo > span{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<nav>
<a href="#" class="nav-logo"><span>Logo</span></a>
    <ul class="nav-menu">
        <li>menu</li>
        <li>menu</li>
        <li>menu</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```